# What is the best way to get the count of the number of items in a Django queryset?

Tags: django, django-models, django-queryset

I am doing a Django query. I want to know how many MyModels there are that have myAttribute value of "X". This is how I am doing it:

```
len(MyModel.objects.filter(myAttribute="X"))
```

Is this the most efficient way to handle it? I am concerned that this unnecessarily gets more data from the database than I need and instead I should be using the Count() function. However, from examples I have seen posted I am unsure if I can combine Count() with filter(). Can someone please advise?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The most optimal way to just get the count is to use [count()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#count):

```
MyModel.objects.filter(myAttribute="X").count()
```

Comment: Just to add, the key recognition is that django querysets are chainable.